# HDD 100% disk usage on idle but 0% usage on SMART scan

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, performance

Recently I got a new internal HDD ( replaced old one which had bad sectors ) for my HP Pavilion au003tx laptop and it has been giving me micro-stutters and random freezes.

Even playing a 720p video in VLC was causing random freezes. I tried every possible fix - Update all drivers/Windows, disabled almost everything on Win 10 ( search, Superfetch, BITS, Auto Updater, background Apps, Telemetry, Tips and more ), chkdsk and defragged the drive, removed all programs from Startup but to no rescue. CrystalDiskInfo and SMART tests also gave no problem.

Weird thing was playing games on 720p resolution was causing almost no problems ( maybe a couple framedrops ). So, here is something weird I noticed, I downloaded HDDScan software for scanning my HDD and while it was doing the extended SMART test there is 0-2% disk usage ( with rare spikes to 20-30% ). I even watched an entire 2 hour 720p movie with no stutter/lag ( with the scan in background )

So I am puzzled what could be the issue!

PS. It is a fresh install ( 2 weeks back ) and i don't use Antivirus as well.